# How to grep for all the files in a directory that do not have a set of file extensions?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

In a given directory or say a report file that contains a list of names of files with various extensions. Basically I want to list down files that are not of few set of file extensions. say .log, .html, .txt. Can someone please help me to exactly grep excluding these set of file extensions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below grep command.

```
grep -vE '.*\.(log|html|txt)$' file
```

From `man grep`

```
-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
```

Comment: apologies for my silly question. Thanks for your solution. It worked :)

Comment: that was my 1st question on stackoverflow. :) point noted .. will follow that from next time onwards :) thank you